# MS SQL != and <> clause didn't show all differences

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with my sql query. It shows only 100% percent differences,
in WHERE clause at 7th line " OrSp_Amount != OrSp_CompletedAmount".

First select works fine, but the second one didnt shows  partial differences. (20-5, 40-3 , only 45-0 for example)

I've tried to use '<>' too, but it changed nothing.

Any ideas :)  ?

```
WITH Orders_CTE
AS
(
    SELECT  [OrSp_ProductInWarehouseId], [OrSp_CompletedFromInvoice], [OrSp_Amount], [OrSp_TaxRate], [OrSp_CompletedAmount], OrSp_Price ,
     OrSp_OrderHeaderId , Orde_ClientId
    FROM  data.AllOrders 
    JOIN [data].[AllOrderPositions]WITH(INDEX([IX_OrSp_OrderHeaderId])) ON [Orde_Id] = [OrSp_OrderHeaderId]
    WHERE [Orde_ShipmentDate] BETWEEN '2016-06-01' AND '2017-01-01' AND [Orde_ClientId] = 17467  AND  OrSp_Amount != OrSp_CompletedAmount
)

    SELECT  OrSp_ProductInWarehouseId, 17467 as ClientID, 
    SUM(Orders_CTE.OrSp_Price) as Price,
    SUM(OrSp_Amount) as Amount, 
    SUM(OrSp_Price * OrSp_Amount) as TotalNetValue ,
    SUM(OrSp_CompletedFromInvoice) as CompletedFromInvoice,
    SUM(OrSp_CompletedAmount) as CompletedAmount,
    SUM(OrSp_Price * OrSp_CompletedFromInvoice) as CompletedValue,
    SUM(OrSp_CompletedFromInvoice) / nullif(SUM(OrSp_Amount),0) as AmountRealizationPlaceholder,
    SUM(OrSp_TaxRate*OrSp_Price + OrSp_Price) * SUM(OrSp_CompletedFromInvoice) / nullif(SUM((OrSp_TaxRate * OrSp_Price) + OrSp_Price),0) * SUM(OrSp_Amount) as ValueRealizationPlaceholder
    FROM Orders_CTE JOIN [data].[Products] as Products ON Orders_CTE.OrSp_ProductInWarehouseId = Prod_Id 
    GROUP BY OrSp_ProductInWarehouseId, OrSp_OrderHeaderId
```

Comment: `!=` is just a deprecated alternative to `<>`.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and then edit!

Comment: What do you mean with 100% differences and partial differences? 2 Things are equal or different, there are no degrees of 'differencesness'. Can you add sample data to show what you mean?

Comment: `<>` is ANSI Strandard and `!=` is not. There is no logical difference between the two.

Comment: Are there `NULL`s in our data? Those always cause a headache.

Comment: [link](https://zapodaj.net/e67e9e886150b.png.html)  Its situation when we have always zero in amount or complete amount column.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is not possible to test for NULL values with comparison operators, so in case value of field OrSp_Amount or OrSp_CompletedAmount is NULL, you cannot obtain any meaningful results.

You could try to change the WHERE clause to:

```
COALESCE(OrSp_Amount, 0) <> COALESCE(OrSp_CompletedAmount, 0)
```

Comment: still the same problem, i think it doesn't help :(

Comment: Does the first query (*WITH Orders_CTE AS ...*) run correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is resolved. I have forget to add "LEFT" at join in second SELECT and some records with values bigger than 0 in complete amount were "lost".